# bootstrap wrong media query taking effect

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a container, which is displayed on a screen at 873 pixels width, but the media query max-width: 540 is taking effect, while the one that should apply, max-width: 720, is showing cut out in chrome dev tools.[image]

Comment: *"which is displayed on a screen at 873"* .. how do you know that the screen width is 873px?

Comment: I printed {window.innerWidth} in my react app, which is displaying on the page as 873

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the order of media query in CSS that _grid.scss file.

First with media(min-width: 576px) and then put media(min-width: 768px).